# Issue with loading jackson libraries because of CaSe difference in Java

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, swagger, dropwizard

There is a dependency on com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonschema/SchemaAware in my project. I have built a fatJar using gradle and dropwizard db migrations give the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonschema/SchemaAware
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:450)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:366)
    at io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:19)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:61)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:67)
    at com.flipkart.birbal.BirbalApplication.main(BirbalApplication.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema.SchemaAware
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
```

The fatJar has reference to com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonSchema/SchemaAware.class. So, there is a CaSe difference in jsonSchema.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile(
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-hibernate:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:' + dropwizardVersion,
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:' + groovyVersion,
            'org.projectlombok:lombok:' + lombokVersion,
            'mysql:mysql-connector-java:' + mysqlConnectorVersion,
            'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:' + morphiaVersion,
            'commons-net:commons-net:' + commonsNetVersion,
            'com.google.inject:guice:' + guiceVersion,
            'commons-threadpool:commons-threadpool:' + commonsThreadpoolVersion,
            'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:' + commonsLang3Version,
            'com.hubspot.dropwizard:dropwizard-guice:' + dropWizardGuiceVersion,
            'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:' + opencsvVersion,
            'io.federecio:dropwizard-swagger:' + swaggerVersion,
            'org.mockftpserver:MockFtpServer:' + mockFtpServerVersion,
            'commons-io:commons-io:' + commonsIoVersion,
            'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:' + gparsVersion,
            'org.gperfutils:gprof:' + gperfVersion,
            'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:' + jsonSimpleVersion
    )

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
```

}

**gradle.properties**

```
dropwizardVersion=0.7.1
groovyVersion=2.3.6
lombokVersion=1.12.4
guiceVersion=3.0
commonsThreadpoolVersion=20030513.073905
dropWizardGuiceVersion=0.7.1
commonsLang3Version=3.3.1
mysqlConnectorVersion=5.1.28
commonsNetVersion=3.3
opencsvVersion=2.3
morphiaVersion=0.108
swaggerVersion=0.5.2
mockFtpServerVersion=2.4
commonsIoVersion=2.4
gparsVersion=1.2.1
gperfVersion=0.3.0-groovy-2.3
jsonSimpleVersion=1.1
```

This happened because of dependency on Swagger. Swagger pulls in jackson-module-jsonSchema which has the package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonSchema which doesn't have SchemaAware class. SchemaAware class is available in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema (jackson-databind).

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: There must be another library with the reference to `jsonSchema` version that is overriding the one you need. If you can paste your `build.gradle` we might be able to pinpoint it.

Comment: Added build.gradle and gradle.properties.

Comment: It seems swagger pulls in `jackson-module-jsonSchema` which has the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonSchema` which does not have the class `SchemaAware` is in the `jackson-databind` `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema`. I don't have the solution, but I think this is something to look into. Seems to be conflicting. Try to excluse the swagger dependency and see if it works. If it does, then you can work on fixing the conflict. I don't know if the casing of the packages is a conflict, causing the lower case not to be built to the fat jar

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the reason for the issue. I excluded Swagger dependency and it worked.